# Data validation applied to any highlighted column that allows values with specific text

Tags: excel, vba

I need the code to

1.) look for a string in the header (in this example, let's say "Email")

2.) highlight the entire column containing that header name

3.) apply data validation that will only allow values with "@" in it

I have the ff code. It highlights the column and runs the validation but I get incorrect output. It still gives me a warning even when entering texts with "@"

```
Sub FindAddressColumn()
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xRgUni As Range
Dim xFirstAddress As String
Dim xStr As String

On Error Resume Next

xStr = "Email"
Set xRg = Range("A1:BZ1").Find(xStr, , xlValues, xlWhole, , , True)
If Not xRg Is Nothing Then
    xFirstAddress = xRg.Address
    Do
        Set xRg = Range("A1:BZ1").FindNext(xRg)
        If xRgUni Is Nothing Then
            Set xRgUni = xRg
        Else
            Set xRgUni = Application.Union(xRgUni, xRg)
        End If
    Loop While (Not xRg Is Nothing) And (xRg.Address <> xFirstAddress)
End If

xRgUni.EntireColumn.Select

 With Selection.Validation
    .Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertWarning, Operator _
    :=xlBetween, Formula1:="=ISNUMBER(FIND(""@"",))"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .ErrorTitle = "Invalid Email"
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

I'm thinking if it's something with the validation formula. Thanks in advance!

Comment: FIND() takes two arguments, not one.

Comment: ..however I'm not sure you can reliably add a formula-based validation to a multi-area range formed using Union()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can union all of the columns and apply a formula-based validation: easier to process each column separately.

Also the find/findnext logic is better factored out into a reusable function.

```vb
Sub SetUpEmailValidation()
    
    Dim allHdrs As Collection, c As Range, rng As Range
    
    Set allHdrs = FindAll(Range("A1:BZ1"), "Email")
    For Each c In allHdrs
        Set rng = c.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rows.Count - c.Row)
        With rng.Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertWarning, Operator:=xlBetween, _
                 Formula1:="=ISNUMBER(FIND(""@""," & rng.Cells(1).Address(False, False) & "))"
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .ErrorTitle = "Invalid Email"
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End With
    Next c
End Sub

'find all cells with matching values in a range
Public Function FindAll(rng As Range, val As String) As Collection
    Dim rv As New Collection, f As Range
    Dim addr As String
    Set f = rng.Find(what:=val, after:=rng.Cells(rng.Cells.Count), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then addr = f.Address()
    Do Until f Is Nothing
        rv.Add f
        Set f = rng.FindNext(after:=f)
        If f.Address() = addr Then Exit Do
    Loop
    Set FindAll = rv
End Function
```